# Dynamic mapping in Nest 1.4

Tags: elasticsearch, dynamic, mapping, nest

I am working on Nest version 1.4  . Currently I am handling csv files with column names varying in every new insertion. In order to do that I have to chamge my class name every now and then, eg suppose

Suppose there are only three fields in csv file like severity,entity_type and operation then I define my class like this

[ElasticProperty(Name = "severity", Store = true, Index = FieldIndexOption.NotAnalyzed, Type = FieldType.String)]
        public string severity { get; set; }

```
    [ElasticProperty(Name = "entity_type", Store = true, Index = FieldIndexOption.NotAnalyzed, Type = FieldType.String)]
    public string entity_type { get; set; }

    [ElasticProperty(Name = "operation", Store = true, Index = FieldIndexOption.NotAnalyzed, Type = FieldType.String)]
    public string operation { get; set; }
```

But in another csv file i have a new field called "number", then again i need to add this attribute to this class which becomes tedious. Is there something called dynamic mapping in nest version 1.4 that can automatically map the column names from the csv files? Also I tried with MULTI-FIELD MAPPING but it doesnt seem to work. Please suggest.

Thanks
Nilanjana

Comment: What version of Elasticsearch are you targeting?

Comment: Hi Russ, I am actually working on Elasticsearch version 1.4. and Nest version 1.4

Comment: I would recommend upgrading to the latest NEST 1.x version, which is compatible with Elasticsearch 1.4: https://www.nuget.org/packages/NEST/1.9.2

Comment: Hi Russ, yes I tried using this version but I am not able to map it dynamically @runtime. My usecase is without  defining a class/ structure for the field , I should be able to map it directly from the csv. Can that be done? If yes, please give me an example